# How can I change the value of the cell A2 to "Today()" when I make any change in the cell A1?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-macros

I am doing my project management in a Google Spreadsheet. A script that automates changes in my comment field to my change_date-field =TODAY() would help me to save some time and also use this function for other scripts I might need in the future.

When I make changes in a comment-field currently, I have to manually enter the change date in my change_date-field which is something that could be easily automated, I think.

Unfortunately I have no clue how to write the code for this.

When I am making any changes in my column named "comment" I want to return the value "=TODAY()" in the column named "change_date". Can you guys help me out with a script that does this job for me automatically?

Comment: Just to make sure you're aware, `=today()` will update to today's date automatically so if you're trying to get a static date timestamp in the change_date column this won't achieve your goal, you could however use a script to set the value of the cell to a timestamp.

Comment: Oh you are right, thank you! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be helpful if you could share a version of the spreadsheet you are referring to to help us answer more accurately.

Based on the information provided some ideas that might help you might be:
1. Use `setFormula` to change the requested cell to today(). Something like

```
function setToday() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange('B1'); //Set the cell here
 range.setFormula('=today()');
}
```

2. Add the date in using the script directly

```
    function newDate() {
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     var range = sheet.getRange('B1'); //Set the cell here
     var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'dd//MM/yy');
     range.setValue(today);
    }
```

You could use an onEdit trigger to update the cells when a specific cell is edited.

```
function onEdit(e){
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var range = e.range;
 var column = range.getColumn();
 var row = range.getRow();
 if (column==2) { //Replace 2 with the column number of your comments cell//
   var newRange = sheet.getRange(row,column+1); //If the date is in the next column
 newRange.setFormula('=today()');
 }
```

Sorry I couldn't be more specific.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nMYDc4oGcl9YwB3vAcH3lq9_Vr0OWT0IN8zriDFGEco/edit?usp=sharing

This is the spreadsheet with the main idea. Unfortunately I have no clue how to setup your script with this one.

Comment: I have added a script (see for yourself in Tools>Script Editor) which has the functionality I described above.  If you require the script to work in another spreadsheet then copy and paste the script and add it to the script editor for your other spreadsheet.  If this helps please accept my answer as useful or let me know how I can help further.

Comment: Thanks so much, you were a great help! :D